# How can i compare two numbers inside input field using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to match two randomly generated numbers. I want to add `ng-invalid` class if result wrongly enter. In the controller this function is generating the numbers.

### AngularJs

```
    $scope.getRandomSpan = function(){
            return Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
}
```

### HTML

```
<span ng-init="a=getRandomSpan()">{{ a }}</span>
<span ng-init="b=getRandomSpan()"> + {{ b }}</span>
```

I want to validate the numbers once user enter number in input field.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="captcha" required />
```

For example function generate two numbers 2 and 3 `(equal to 5)`, now i want to add `ng-invalid` class if entered number not equal to 5. I have done this task in the controller which is validating after submit the form.

```
var random =  $scope.a + $scope.b;
var enteredcaptcha =  $scope.captcha;
if(random == enteredcaptcha){...}
```

But i don't know how to validate on the spot, can any one guide me about this I will appreciate. Thank You for guideline

Comment: i think you should use the two way databinding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have updated my code and it will display message if you enter correct value otherwise nothing happen

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.getRandomSpan = function() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  }
  $scope.$watch("captcha", function() {
    var random = $scope.a + $scope.b;
    var enteredcaptcha = $scope.captcha;
    if (enteredcaptcha) {
      var myEl = angular.element(document.querySelector('#ans'));
      if (random == enteredcaptcha) {
        myEl.addClass("ng-valid").removeClass("ng-invalid");
      } else {
        myEl.addClass("ng-invalid").removeClass("ng-valid");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#ans {
  display: none;
}

.ng-invalid{
  display:none !important;
}

.ng-valid{
  display:inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <span ng-init="a=getRandomSpan()">{{ a }}</span>
  <span ng-init="b=getRandomSpan()"> + {{ b }}</span>
  <input type="number" ng-model="captcha" />
  <span id="ans">excellent!!!!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing knowledge, its working fine as explain, but can we add ng-invalid class instead of `alert("not equal");`

Comment: where you want to add class?

Comment: On same input but i'm not using jquery, so is this possible to add class using angularjs. Thanks for guiding me

Comment: That's still not very angular-ish ;) I'd recommend either using ng-class or a custom validator (which seems overkill in this case). +1 for the effort though

Comment: @Aaron thanks for showing interest can you kindly explain.

Comment: @Mr.Developer I'll post another answer

Answer (score 1):

To conditionally set a class on an element, you can use the [`ngClass` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). It accepts 3 different syntaxes, but one of the simplest is the following :

```
<input type="number" ng-model="captcha" required ng-class="{'ng-invalid': a+b!=captcha, 'ng-valid': a+b==captcha}"/>
```

I assume that `a`, `b` and `captcha` are reachable from the `input`'s scope.

Of course since the class you want to add is `ng-invalid`, you're trying to do form validation. A more integrated way to do this would be to use angular's [custom validation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation).

Comment: I could expand on custom validation but I'm not proficient with validators nor directives, so I think reading the documentation will be best